# NSTableColumn identifier is "_NS:9"

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, nstablecolumn

I'm trying to implement a NSTableView. I added some columns from xib, and on some of them i added a identifier. But when running the app, on
    `-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row`
 all the columns identifier are "_NS:9".

Any help? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you aren't accessing the column *identifier*:

```
- (id)          tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                      row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSLog(@"Column identifier is '%@'", tableColumn.identifier);
    //                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was calling "tableView.identifier"